# How to add a custom property to a UserControl which display as a combo box at the design time

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

**Edit:**
The question is about adding a property **during the design time**, not **during the runtime**.

I created a UserControl, in which contains a button, and I want to add a new property that when user uses it in form, he could see the property `FillColor` in user control's `Property Tab`. What's more, that property should be in the form of a combobox, which allows user to select the `Color` in System.Drawing.Color.

For Example:

I call my UserControl `HalfFill`. What it does is to fill a normal button from start to the half of he size.

Now I want 2 properties to be customized using `Property Tab`:

- the first half color
- the second half color

And when user chooses the color , the choices are listed in combobox (behaves like `BackColor` property for normal buttons), and all of them come from System.Drawing.Color.

I want to do it with Enum. Can someone help me? How i put the comboxBox with its values into the `Properties Tab`?

Here is an example that I am looking for

```
public partial class HalfButton: UserControl
{
    public ComboBox ChooseColor //of all color in System.Drawing.Color
    {
        /* must be in that comboBox all the color in Color library so the user could choose 
        from properies of the button the color he want */

        get { return x.Item[colorfill.ToString()); }
        set { colorfill = Color.FromName(value); OnPaint(null); }
    }

    private Color colorfill = Color.Tomato;

    ComboBox x;

    public HalfButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        x = new ComboBox();
        ArrayList ColorList = new ArrayList();
        Type colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
        PropertyInfo[] propInfoList = colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static |
                                                              BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                              BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (PropertyInfo c in propInfoList)
        {
            x.Items.Add(c.Name);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(colorfill+""); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want add a property to your user control you have to add a property to user control code behind. Better if you can add some codes to this question that will be easy to answer.

Comment: i already had
i just dont know how to make it like comboBox/Enum with all colors

Comment: You want to know how to bind a combo box using enum. is that your problem

Comment: yes here i did edit what i looking for

Comment: You want the property during **design time** don't you (the one shows in the `Property Tab` in the IDE like Visual Studio)? or you want it to be in the runtime (a combo box in the form, and the color should be filled in the runtime)? please clarify yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the property in the `Designer`? Please take a look at my example below.

I created a `UserControl` called `ColorTextBox`, and defined a property called `FilledColor`. In the designer, I am able to change the color in a combo box:

The property is shown in the `Property Tab`:

[image: The property is shown in the Property Tab]

Colors in the combobox, Drawing.Colors are under `Web` tab:

[image: Colors in the ComboBox]

After change the `FilledColor` to `Highlight`:

[image: after change]

My code is fairly simple:

```
private Color _filledColor;

public ColorTextBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _filledColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control);
}

public Color FilledColor
{
    get { return _filledColor; }
    set
    {
        _filledColor = value;
        button1.BackColor = _filledColor;
    }
}
```

The only change is to change your property type to Color, and the magic completed.

Comment: ty that what i Search For

Answer (score 1):

following code will give you an idea how you can bind the combo using System.Drawing.Color.
Also need to use namespace using System.Reflection;

```
ArrayList ColorList = new ArrayList();
        Type colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
        PropertyInfo[] propInfoList = colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (PropertyInfo c in propInfoList)
        {
            this.comboBox1.Items.Add(c.Name);
        }
```

Comment: More details on this site http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/renuka11/using-a-combobox-to-select-colors/

Comment: thank you for getting all type of Color but still problem
ok now i have comboBox with AllColor
how i can show it in propeties??
i mean
i wanna that when user use the that control, he will have in propeties of that control:
like background have comboBox of colors
combobox of all that color (the code you gave me)
i mean i can fill the comboBox but how i bind that comboBox in propeties???

Comment: Your combobox inside user controll or in the page that you use your user control. can you tell that then I can give you a solution

Comment: public ComboBox ChooseColor //of all color in System.Drawing.Color
    {
/* must be in that comboBox all the color in Color library so the user could choose 
from properies of the button the color he want */

        get { return x.Item[colorfill.ToString()); }
        set { colorfill = Color.FromName(value); OnPaint(null); }

    }

    private Color colorfill = Color.Tomato;
         ComboBox x;

Comment: If I simplify what you want like this, your user control have a button. that button background color you want to set using a property in the user control. then where ever you use this user control you can set background color. Is that what you want.

Comment: i dont wanna use the normal background color 
cause in the button i need 2 properties with comboBox
1)halfOneColor>values(red,blue,green...)
2)halftwoColor>Values(red,blue,green...)

i need that comboBox with colorName inside and option to choose from the Page the Color

Comment: can you put screen shot of your user control because I want to understand combobox and your property relationship.

Answer (score 1):

That my last version...
now i only need to bind the comboBox values (that in the combBox) to the properties
when i try that it show

ChooseColor1 | None

```
    public static ComboBox ComboFill()
             {
                 ComboBox xx = new ComboBox();
                 ArrayList ColorList = new ArrayList();
                 Type colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
                 PropertyInfo[] propInfoList = colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);
                 foreach (PropertyInfo c in propInfoList)
                 {
                     xx.Items.Add(c.Name);
                 }
                 return xx;
             }
           private Color colorfill1 = Color.Tomato;
           private Color colorfill2 = Color.Tomato;
           private ComboBox x1=ComboFill();
           private ComboBox x2=ComboFill();

     public ComboBox ChooseColor1 {

            get { return x1; }
            set { x1=value; OnPaint(null); }

        }
     public ComboBox ChooseColor2 {

            get { return x2; }
            set { x2=value; OnPaint(null); }

        }

     protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                    //my functions
//something with colorfill1
//something with colorfill2


            }
```

Comment: you'd better edit your original post instead of adding an answer here :)